Can I change the Default Mannequin to a paragon character
I tried somethings on the paragon characters but animations are not perfectly match and locomotion systems are not perfectly working so I decided for work on the default ABP_Mannequin and I have to try replace the paragon character. How can I do that?
(my english is not very good so sorry for the weirdness)
